# Formatting large currency numbers

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using the FormatStyle APIs, is there a way to format large numbers with trailing SI units like "20M" or "10k"? In particular I'm looking for a way to format large currency values like "$20M" with proper localization and currency symbols.

I currently have a currency formatter:

```
extension FormatStyle where Self == FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency {
    public static var dollars: FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency {
        .currency(code: "usd").precision(.significantDigits(2))
    }
}
```

I'd like to extend this to format `Double(20_000_000)` as "$20M".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `struct` that conforms to `FormatStyle`

```
public struct ShortCurrency<Value>: FormatStyle, Equatable, Hashable, Codable where Value :  BinaryFloatingPoint{
    let locale: Locale
    enum Options: Int{
        case million = 2
        case billion = 3
        case trillion = 4
        
        func short(locale: Locale) -> String{
            switch self {
            case .million:
                return millionAbbr[locale, default: "M"]
            case .billion:
                return billionAbbr[locale, default: "B"]
            case .trillion:
                return trillionAbbr[locale, default: "T"]
            }
        }
        ///Add other supported locales
        var millionAbbr: [Locale: String] { [Locale(identifier: "en_US") : "M"]}
        var billionAbbr: [Locale: String]  { [Locale(identifier: "en_US") : "B"]}
        var trillionAbbr: [Locale: String]  { [Locale(identifier: "en_US") : "T"]}
    }
    public func format(_ value: Value) -> String {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.locale = locale
        f.numberStyle = .currency
        f.usesSignificantDigits = true

        let basic = f.string(for: value) ?? "0"
        let count = basic.count(of: ".000")
        //Checks for million value
        if let abbr = Options(rawValue: count)?.short(locale: f.locale){
            //Get the symbol and the most significant numbers
            var short = String(basic.prefix(basic.count - (4*count)))
            //Append from the dictionary based on locale
            short.append(abbr)
            //return modified string
            return short
        }else{
            //return the basic string
            return basic
        }
    }
    
}

extension String {
    
    func count(of string: String) -> Int {
        guard !string.isEmpty else{
            return 0
        }
        var count = 0
        var searchRange: Range<String.Index>?
        
        while let foundRange = range(of: string, options: .regularExpression, range: searchRange) {
            count += 1
            searchRange = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: foundRange.upperBound, upper: endIndex))
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

Then extend `FormatStyle`

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
extension FormatStyle where Self == FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency {
    public static func shortCurrency (locale: Locale? = nil) -> ShortCurrency<Double> {
        return ShortCurrency(locale: locale ?? .current)
    }
}
```

It will be available for usage just as any other `FormatStyle`

```
Text(Double(20_000_000), format: .shortCurrency())
```

Comment: Thanks. It's really helpful to have an example of writing a non-trivial formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You can format ordinary numbers this way using the `notation` modifier with `compactName` as argument

```
Double(20_000_000).formatted(.number.notation(.compactName))
```

Unfortunately this modifier doesn't exist for `Currency` although it also exists for `Percent` so hopefully this is something we will see implemented in the future.

So the question is if this is good enough or if it is worth it to implement a custom solution.

Comment: I wish I could accept multiple answers. :) lorem ipsum's answer will probably be more precise for people who search this question, but yours is how I've actually chosen to solve the problem, and is definitely close enough for my purposes (I could add the currency symbol if I wanted, but I'm actually kind of preferring to save the space now that I look at it). I tried going down this road originally, but because I'm actually using this in a AxisValueLabel, Swift was having trouble type checking it. Once I saw that it was possible, I finally fixed the type checking problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After digging more deeply into this, I've developed a solution that get the best of Joakim Danielson and lorem ipsum's answers, using `.compactName` to avoid reimplementing unit scaling, while still getting a currency symbol.

It's important that this is not a fully localized solution, which is quite difficult. In American English, 20 million euros would commonly be written "€20M", but in French there's no common practice I can find. Something like "20 M€" seems more likely from my research. But how would "millions of Canadian dollars" be written in French? Where does the space go? "20 MCA$"? "20 M CAD"? It's a mess just looking at American English and French, let alone every other supported Locale and currency.

But that's not the problem I'm solving. I'm the only user of this program and I just want to display quantities of US Dollars. How do I write a formatter that does just what I want?

Just like the Percent formatter and the Currency formatter, create a ShortDollars formatter nested inside of FloatingPointFormatStyle:

```
extension FloatingPointFormatStyle {
    public struct ShortDollars: FormatStyle {
        public func format(_ value: Value) -> String {
            let s = FloatingPointFormatStyle()
                .precision(.significantDigits(2))
                .notation(.compactName)
                .format(value)
            return "$\(s)"
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the standard FloatingPointFormatStyle for all the heavy lifting, and then slaps a `$` on the front.

And to give it the standard syntax, add static properties (you need this for each specific type of BinaryFloatingPoint this can format):

```
extension FormatStyle where Self == FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.ShortDollars {
    public static var shortDollars: Self { .init() }
}

extension FormatStyle where Self == FloatingPointFormatStyle<Float>.ShortDollars {
    public static var shortDollars: Self { .init() }
}
```